# CloudKit: annot use instance member 'predicate' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Tags: swift, nspredicate, cloudkit, xcode12

I'm trying to build a query in CloudKit:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Movie", predicate: predicate)
let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot use instance member 'predicate' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
```

[image]

Any of you knows why I'm getting this error?

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you have a class property named `query` up above in your code? I think we need to see more of your code since it looks like a conflict of some kind or a an issue with the context of where you are doing this. Your CloudKit syntax looks right to me.

Comment: @CliftonLabrum No I don't have any `query` property above this code. I don't any conflicts any where else. The conflict is the predicate for some reason.

Comment: exact same code works for me...I'd agree with @CliftonLabrum - we need to see more code as it it likely something above is triggering the error, even if it isn't be called out as such

Comment: Wait, that kind of error. Where is that code? Inside a `init()`, that's where you are declaring the properties of your custom struct/class?